# EFI Boot Frozen When Trying to Install Windows 8.1

Tags: bootcamp, startup, performance

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp on my Mac Pro Early 2009 Edition which should be possible according to this page:

https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT201457

I went through all of the steps and got the software onto my USB drive, etc.  When I reboot the mac and hold the option key I see 3 options.  Main, Restore and EFI Boot, however, when I click the EFI boot, the mouse freezes and nothing happens.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Thanks!

Craig

Comment: I don't think the installation has finished. EFI Boot is not the name of the Windows partition Boot Camp created. It should be Windows. After you select the partition for Windows on Boot Camp and Windows files have been copied to your USB flash drive, it will restart to start running your Windows installer. You don't have to choose the boot disk just yet, it will automatically run the installer where you can then choose the partition you created in Boot Camp as the Windows installation partition.

Comment: Did you have to do something special to create the USB drive? Usually, the 2009 model Macs can not install Windows using a USB flash drive installer. The believe the preferred method is to use the optical drive. Also, there is a fairly good chance you are suppose to select the icon labelled "Windows" not "EFI Boot". In other words, you are suppose to do a BIOS/MBR install, not a EFI/GPT install.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yeah I read somewhere that you had to use the optical drive but that page I linked to said early 2009 Mac pros would work.  I don't mind using the optical drive but I don't know how to copy the usb to a dvd so that it stays bootable.  When I boot it up and hold down ctrl the only 3 options I get are Main which is my current OS X install, system restore which I assume is for reinstalling OS X and then that EFI boot.  Those are the only choices at the moment.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Starting with El Capitan, you have to use the Finder to burn an iso to DVD.

Comment: Still on yosemite

Answer (score 1):

If you want to EFI boot the installer you need to [flash your firmware from MacPro4,1 to MacPro5,1](http://forum.netkas.org/index.php/topic,852.0.html).

Create an installer like mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1045512/how-can-i-create-windows-install-media-that-boots-installs-uefi-only) without any bootmgr files to force an EFI boot.

Remove all disks from Mac Pro to avoid further trouble with Mac EFI looking for MBR or protected MBR.

EFI boot your installer.

Be sure to clean the unneeded Bootcamp partition and [create GPT install target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/dn336946.aspx).

See also [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238744/efi-boot-windows-8-1-or-10-install-on-macpro4-1-mac-pro-early-2009/238907#238907).

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2007 iMac and a 2011 iMac. I can install both OS X and Ubuntu (Linux) using a flash drive. Both operating systems use the modern EFI/GPT boot/partitioning method. I can not install Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 using a flash drive on either model. Rather, I use a reusable RW DVD and install using the legacy BIOS/MBR boot/partition method. When holding down the alt/option key at startup, a "Windows" labeled icon indicates a BIOS/MBR install. A "EFI Boot" icon represents a EFI/GPT install. Since your Mac is a 2009 model, I would assume the same would apply to you.

If you have the iso and are using Yosemite, you can burn a DVD using the Disk Utility. Open the Disk Utility and drag the icon representing the iso file from the Finder to the Disk Utility. Highlight the iso file and click on the Burn icon located at the top of the Disk Utility window.